# How to download pygame 3.4.1

Tags: python, module, download, pygame

I tried to download pygame 3.2 from pygame.org and from bittbucket 3.3 pygame and I run IDLE and it always gives me an error:

```
No module named 'pygame'
```

I have python version 3.4.1 on windows 7. I need to get pygame for a new thing I am trying to create.

Answer (score 1):

The pygame binary for python 3.4 is available [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame)

Answer (score 1):

You could always take it down a version to 3.3. Have a look in the folder and see if it is there or just find where the Pygame folder is located and move it into the correct folder. That's what I did when my school didn't have it. I just manually put it in myself and it worked!